# How can a PySpark shell with no worker nodes run jobs?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parallel-processing

I have run the below lines in the pypsark shell (mac, 8 cores).

```
import pandas as pd
df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(dict(a = list(range(1000)))
df.show()
```

I want to count my worker nodes (and see the number of cores on each), so I run the python commands in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38661559/3206926):

```
sc.getExecutorMemoryStatus().keys()
# JavaObject id=o151

len([executor.host() for executor in sc.statusTracker().getExecutorInfos() ]) -1
# 0
```

The above code indicates I have 1 worker. So, I checked the the spark UI I only have the driver with 8 cores:[image]

Can work be done by the cores in the driver? If so, are 7 cores doing work and 1 is reserved for "driver" functionality? Why aren't worker nodes being created automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not up to Spark to figure out the perfect cluster for the hardware you provide (although it's highly task-specific what is a *perfect* infrastructure anyway)

Actually, a behaviour you described is default for Spark to set up infrastructure like this if you run on YARN master (see spark.executor.cores option in the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#execution-behavior)).

To modify it you have to either add some options while running `pyspark-shell` or do in inside your code with, for example:

```
conf = spark.sparkContext._conf.setAll([('spark.executor.memory', '4g'), ('spark.executor.cores', '4'), ('spark.cores.max', '4'), ('spark.driver.memory','4g')])
spark.sparkContext.stop()
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
```

More on that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41886346/spark-2-1-0-session-config-settings-pyspark) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59193893/increase-the-spark-workers-cores).

Comment: Thanks @mckraqs for the resources. Going through them now.

Comment: So the cores on the driver are actually doing executor work, despite being on the driver?

Comment: Yup, if no worker nodes are specified, master is doing the work too.